# File Size of attachment becoming 0 (compressed) in Python Django email automation i.e. file name appears, no content shows in attached pdf

Tags: python, django, web, smtp

The code to send email in Django is written like this in views.py file - it sends the pdf fine, if the file size is large (~3mb), but for smaller files (~1 or 2mb) it does not send the file (it appears as a zero byte file) in the email, and hence we cannot access it.
The code is as belows -
Please let me know if there is a way to avoid such a compression of file and send small files to.

```
def addbeast(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BeastForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # print("here")
        # print(form.cleaned_data['name'])
        if form.is_valid():
            # print("here")
            # print(form.cleaned_data['media'])
            form.save()

            # media = Beast.objects.get(name = '')
            name  = form.cleaned_data['name']
            media = form.cleaned_data['media']
            media.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
            filesize = media.tell()
            print(filesize)
            
            subject = "NDA IS Attached"
            message = "NDA Attachment from " + name 
            
            sender = "-----@gmail.com"
            cc_myself = True
            cc_mail = "----!!!!!!@gmail.com"

            recipients = ['9999999999@gmail.com']
            if cc_myself:
                recipients.append(cc_mail)


            
            try:
                mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, sender, recipients)

                mail.attach(media.name, media.read(), media.content_type)
                mail.send()
                return HttpResponse("FORM SUBMISSION IS SUCCESSFUL")
            except:
                return HttpResponse('no success')


            
    else:
        form = BeastForm()


    return render(request, "post_list.html", {
        "form": form
    })
```

Please help with how the code can be made right, on printing the variable media, I get 'filename.pdf'.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting "media.seek(0)" before the line "mail.attach(media.name..."

Django uses InMemoryUploadedFile if the content length is less than FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE (2.5MB by default), otherwise it uses TemporaryUploadedFile.

Your "media.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)" puts the file's current position at the end. Looks like the subsequent *read* command continues from the current position for in-memory file, but starts from the beginning for temporary files.